# Trying to Eliminate Players in a Tournament via button

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to implement the update route into a poker site I am building. I have been able to get the players to appear on the show page but I would like to update the mongo DB from inTournament: "Yes" to inTournament: "No" when the Eliminate button is selected for that player. I have included my code below. Thank you, in advance, for any help with this.

======================= app.js UPDATE ROUTE=======================

```
app.get("/seating", function(req, res){
    //Get all players from poker_DB
   Seat.find({inTournament: "Yes"}, function(err, allseats){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          shuffle(allseats);
          res.render("seating", {seats: allseats});
      }
   });
});

//Update player's tournament status
app.put("/seating", function(req, res){
    Seat.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.params.inTournament, function(err, updatedStatus){
       if(err) {
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.send("Data Updated");
       }
    });
});
```

======================= SHOW PAGE=======================

```
<div class ="row text-left" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
            <div class="col-md-4 table table-bordered">
                <h3 class="text-center">Table 1</h3>
                <ol>
                    <% var i = 1; %>
                    <% var j = 0; %>
                    <% seats.forEach(function(seat){ %>
                        <% if(seat.player && i < perTable1){ %>
                                <% console.log(perTable2); %>
                                <li><%= seats[j].player %>
                                <form action"/seating?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="Submit">Eliminate</button>    
                                </form>
                                </li>
                                <% i++ %>
                                <% j++ %>
                        <% } else { %>
                            <% j++ %>
                            <% } %>
                            <% return j; %>
                    <% }); %>
                </ol>
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: and what is the problem , is it working or not ?

Comment: I keep getting a cannot post to seating..

Comment: I am trying to update that person’s inTournament value from Yes to No on button click but keep receiving the cannot post to seating error. I feel I am missing something in the app.js to update the value and then something in the show page to tell it what ID/person to update.